# float right block IE7 bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have two block inside container.
One is inline block and second is block float right.
In IE7 float right block is outside the container down.

When I change places the blocks inside container, all is to fall into place.

How to explain this behavior?

And maybe a solution without changing blocks?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<style>
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.header_text {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 19px;
    line-height: 19px;
    background: green;
}

.text {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.user_info {
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background: red;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    font-size: none;
    line-height: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header_text">
        <span class="text">Text</span>
        <div class="user_info">Hi, <a href="#">Text</a> [ <a href="#">Text</a>]</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: not understandable enough. Whats container?. Is it a div or table. Also what are blocks?

Comment: can you give a some code in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: please, could you post a demo?

Comment: I add code in my question.
Thank you.

Comment: something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/K5HL4/ - Please explain the problem in more detail.

Comment: When I tested in IE7, I have a problem including your example

Comment: In your example code, nothing has `display: inline-block` (and the first line of your question contains: "One is inline block"). Could you make a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) demo that shows the IE7 problem?

Comment: What exactly is the problem in my example when you test it in IE7? - http://jsfiddle.net/K5HL4/ -

Comment: To make a guess, add float: left; to the inline-block and the float_right_block already has float: right; - So the blocks will be in the "container block" horizontaly. You may need to add overflow: auto; to the "container block"

Comment: Also you are not giving the float right box any dimensions. When you float an element, you have to set the width and height.

Comment: Sorry i have problem when remove float: left for .text

Comment: Add float: left to span.text - http://jsfiddle.net/u7Jtt/6/

Answer (score 0):

use div instead of span.

```
<div class="text">Text</div>
```